# Images not appearing in Django template For Loop

Tags: python, django, image, loops, view

[See Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGBcU.png)

[image: HTML Inspector for first image element]

[image: Inspecting page in Chrome]

I want to loop over a directory of static images in Django. The images are being looped over correctly, but something is wrong with my `<img src />` syntax. I've tried many variations on {{ flag }} but can't get anything to work. Can anybody advise?

In settings.py I created the following STATIC_ROOT object:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/TheUnforecastedStorm/Desktop/Code_projects/Portfolio_Site/portfolio_site/entrance/static'
```

In views.py I joined this file path to my image directory and placed the list of images in the context dictionary. I then included this dictionary in my response:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    # Create a dictionary
    context = {}

    # Join images directory to index.html view
    flags = os.listdir(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "entrance/images/"))  
    context['flags'] = flags
    
    # Return response
    return render(request, "entrance/index.html", context)
```

I then looped over these images in my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'entrance/entrance.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'entrance/entrance.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        {% for flag in flags %}
            <img src="{{ flag }}" alt="problem" />
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my templates where i used static images, my source would use the static template tag. Maybe try something like `{% static flag %}`? Edit: An issue that I noticed was that the values in your `flags` list returned by `os.listdir()` will only contain the name of items in that path, not the full path itself. So if the images that you are trying to access are in `entrance/images` try `{% static 'entance/images/' flag %}`.

Comment: first check if you create correct path - because `STATIC_ROOT` is `..../entrance/static` ad you add `entrance/images` so you finally have `..../entrance/static/entrace/images` . Other problem can be that server may sends images only from `STATIC_ROOT` which means `..../entrance/static/` or its subfolders - if you try to use different folder then it will block files for security reason.

Comment: @NathanRoberts Good catch. I updated that line of code to read `<img src="{% static 'entrance/images/' {{flag}} %}" alt="problem" />` but am still getting the same problem. I inspected the page in Chrome and can see that the Request URL is going to the correct directory holding the images: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/entrance/images/ and it appears to be accessing them but for some reason will not display them. I added a screenshot to the top of the question.

Comment: @furas I double-checked that the path I created is correct. I added a screenshot of the page in Inspect mode above - it shows the correct path to the directory. I'm sensing this is an issue with Django templating via accessing {{ flag }} within the context of {% static 'directory/file' %} but I can't figure out the correct way to fix it.

Comment: @Mark1 Can you take a picture of how the html looks like in the inspector for one of the images? It doesn't seem like it is getting the file name from the `{{ flag }}` you put in the src url. Maybe try removing the `{{ }}` from around the word "flag" in your url for the src attribute.

Comment: @NathanRoberts I just added a screenshot of the html inspector with first element highlighted. Is that what you were looking for? I've tried removing the curly braces from flag as well as moving flag with and without curly braces outside of the static code, but no luck so far.

Comment: @Mark1 Yeah that was what I wanted to see. It looks like it isn't generating the urls for the src attribute correctly. I think I might have made a small mistake in the first suggestion I made. Try removing the last "/" from the "entrance/images/" so that your img src attribute looks like `{% static 'entrance/images' flag %}`

Comment: @NathanRoberts That doesn't work either, unfortunately

Comment: @Mark1 Does the generated html change at all with that edit I made?

Comment: @NathanRoberts yes exactly the same

Comment: @Mark1 I'm going to post an answer with a couple of things so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark1 Working off my comments from above, I haven't been able to find anything to confirm it but it seems like the `{% static %}` template tag can only take one extra argument to make a path, so here is something you can try.

In your view:

```
def index(request):
    # Create a dictionary
    context = {}

    # Join images directory to index.html view
    flags = os.listdir(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "entrance/images/"))

    # ADD IN THIS LINE HERE
    flags = ['entrance/images/'+fl for fl in flags]


    context['flags'] = flags
    
    # Return response
    return render(request, "entrance/index.html", context)
```

The line I added in will add "entrance/images/" to the start of all the file names in the directory you are searching.

Then in your template

```
{% for flag in flags %}
   <img src="{% static flag %}" alt="problem" />
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help! I approached a solution last night that got close by looping through a list of urls in views.py, but I still couldn't quite get what I was looking for. Your insight into django static only allowing a single additional argument turned out to be correct.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help